# Android Studio - ndkBuild does not show compilation progress. How turn it on?

Tags: android, compilation, progress, ndk-build

I have native c++ application. I compile it using ndkBuild. In "Build->Build Output" I expect to see the full progress of compilation. Just now it only shows warnings or errors if there are any. However I need to see the list of all files which are compiled. Here is my build.gradle. How can I turn it on?

```
android {
    namespace "..."
    minSdkVersion ...
    targetSdkVersion ...

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file('src/main/jni/Android.mk')
        }
    }
}
```

I use:

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2
AGP 8.2
NDK 25.1.8937393
```